# Trying to access superclass MY_MODEL without static approach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a "multi-client" web app with Codeigniter. But right now I can't access MY_MODEL from the other Models with the `$this->` variable. I have to use a static one. Is that a problem?

MY_Controller.php

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
protected $data = array();
public function __construct($name = null) {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('my_model');
$this->data['mandant']['clientID'] = $session_data['clientID'];
$this->my_model->set_session($this->data['mandant']);
```

MY_Model.php

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
protected static $works = array();
public $worksnot = array();

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
public function set_session($value) {
    self::$works = $value;
    $this->worksnot = $value;
}
```

Tasks_model.php

```
class Tasks_model extends MY_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getAll() {
        print_r(parent::$works);
        print_r($this->worksnot);
```

Shouldn't both ways work? which is preferably?

I made a mock without codeigniter and the inheritance worked immediatley. is it a codeigniter issue?

Comment: my own solution: using the session functions seems reasonable, still not getting why the inheritance doesn't work.

Comment: This should indeed work. And I tested this in my situation and it does work correctly. I take it you put the MY_MODEL.php in the application/core dir?

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected, just need to use the same object. You set the variable and then trying to access it from a different object (that's why it's empty). So you need to do it like this:

```
$this->load->model('Tasks_model');
$this->Tasks_model->set_session('444');
$this->Tasks_model->getAll();
```